# exception while trying to connect to Active Directory

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

As a project for my company I am trying to query two ADs with asp.net c#. A local one and a remote one.
The local one didn't give me any trouble, connected, queried and every thing is working great.

The problem is with the remote one (located in a servers farm at the ISP location).

I am getting the "A local error has occurred" error.

The connection code I wrote:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://[SERVER IP ADDRESS]/OU=[THE OU],DC=[SUB DOMAIN],DC=[COMPANY DOMAIN NAME],DC=co,DC=il", "site\admin", "abc1234");
```

I've checked the port and it is open in the Firewall and I am trying to query the AD users and YES, the users list is not under users, but under a deferent OU.

Maybe some one know this? what to look for? do i need to use the DC part if i am using an IP, i just can't find a documentation about this...

Was I supposed to open 389 port as i read in the documentation???
Thank you,
Erez

Comment: Are you able to connect to AD using LDAP admin tool, like ldp.exe or LdapAdmin (http://ldapadmin.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I can do telnet to the server with the same port...

Comment: Using LdapAdmin/ldp to test connection will also validate connection string and security options

Comment: Could you provide more detail exception information? COM error number?

Comment: More details: When Using the exact same code but connecting true am asp page localy and removing the ip address everything is working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was the order of the directories in the AD, the connection to defferent directories in the AD is done defferently. user is cn and other directories are ou for example...

Thank you,
Erez

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your LDAP library, you probably cannot bind as domain\user format, to a remote AD.  Try using a proper LDAP DN for the Administrator user instead.